# Postman doesn't accept authorization and instead returns login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, postman, asp.net-identity

I've just started experimenting with APIs and making API requests through Postman. Everything is working fine, until I tried setting one of the controllers to "Authorized", when Postman instead decided to return the login page in HTML format. Currently I'm not that concerned with why it does that, but rather why the authorization doesn't work.

The controller I'm trying to call;

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/api/GetRoles")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<IdentityRole>>> GetRoles()
    {
        return await _roleManager.Roles.ToListAsync();
    }
```

What I've done is simply enter the user credentials for the admin account under "Authorization" - "Basic Auth" in Postman, which then creates a Base64 header. The response is a simple "200 OK" status with the html for my login page, which is what would appear if one tried to access this controller in a browser.

For the authorization I've used Identity, which saves all user data in pre-designed database tables.

Any ideas or tips for where to look to figure this out?

Comment: Is the 200 really from your request? Or have you fiddled with the request settings in Postman so that a returned redirect will actually be executed by postman and then you get a 200 from the login page request? I think you should see that in the postman console if a redirect happens. And if yes have a look at the settings of your postman request.

Comment: Your request should have a "Automatically follow redirects" setting that should be off.

Comment: Yes, there was an automatic redirect, now I instead get an empty 302 Found status when sending the request, which I suppose it technically correct since it should redirect if the user is not logged on. But that means the authorization is still not working?

Comment: Correct. Either your credentials are wrong or your implementation of the authentication ;)

Comment: Is this .Net or Core?

Comment: The credentials are correct, I know that much because they work fine to log in with. The authorization part works fine when I use different users with different roles, they all get access as they're supposed to. Is there something specific that has to be done to authenticate from Postman?

This is .Net 5

Comment: Since you're using Core you have to be using some type of auth provider, either IdentityServer (or whatever it's named now) or Active Directory.